# Python functional test for linux command

Tags: python, linux, sorting, testing, functional-testing

I want to write functional tests for linux sort command in python. I am new with writing test cases. While researching i found `Cram` and `pytest` that can be used, but not sure. So any leads or links on how to proceed for writing functional test scripts for linux sort command would be appreciated.

Comment: You found two options. What about them are you not sure of? What about the sort command do you want to tests? Please be more specific. Also, it is harder to help you if you haven't actually tried something.

Comment: I used pytest with selenium to basically test a website. But for functional test I am not sure how can I use ut. Basically I want to write functional test for Linux sort command.

Comment: What functionality in the sort command do you want to test?

Comment: I have to test the output of different options of the sort command like sort -M, sort -n,sort -R

Comment: Test to see how long they take?

Comment: If so, writing a python program to do it directly will likely take less time than learning a testing framework. See the related article, "Calling an external command in Python" and "How to get time of a python program execution?".

Comment: I dont want to check the time of the execution. I want to write the test scripts to test the function of the sort command .

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website of [Python Testing Tools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy). Many of those can do what you need but you will have to investigate and try them. There is a wealth of documentation and tutorials for unittest. Something like TextTest, which "works by comparing plain text logged by programs with a previous 'gold standard' version of that text", may be more of what you are looking to do when testing sort.